# How to use a HTML variable inside another

Tags: html, django

I have a piece of code that loops through some objects. I have another set of objects that I want to loop through too. Is there a way I can use the for loop.counter to increase the image object?

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for project in projects.all %}
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="news-section-single">
                  <div class="news-img-main">
                    <div class="news-img"><img src="{{ images.{{ forloop.counter }}.image.url }}" alt="" data-popupalt-original-title="null" title="">
                      <div class="news-list">
                        <ul>
                          <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ project.date }}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="news-head">
                    <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Hope that makes sense what I'm trying to do.

I'm sure someone will tell me I'm trying to do the wrong thing so here is my views.py

```
def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    images = ProjectImage.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'projects.html', {'projects': projects,
                                             'images': images})
```

And my models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name='images', on_delete='CASCADE')
    image = models.ImageField()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, indeed, you don't want to do any of this. You have a relationship between Project and ProjectImage, you should just pass the projects to the template and use that relationship there.

```
{% for project in projects %}
    ...
    {% for image in project.images.all %} 
    <div class="news-img">
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="" data-popupalt-original-title="null" title="">
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer, to show future readers that it helped you.

Comment: Although you did help me, it wasn't quite the answer i was looking for. but 100% you got me there. I've posted  the answer i used below.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used in the end.

```
<div class="row">
        {% for project in projects.all %}
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="news-section-single">
                  <div class="news-img-main">
                    <div class="news-img"><img src="{{ project.images.first.image.url }}" alt="" data-popupalt-original-title="null" title="">
                      <div class="news-list">
                        <ul>
                          <li><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ project.date }}</li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="news-head">
                    <h3>{{ project.title }}</h3>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```